# How to simulate touch events and send them to foreground activity (On device)

Tags: android, android-input-method

I wish to be able to send touch events to the foreground Activity.
**Assume that I don't have control over the foreground Activity**. For example sending touch events to Android Gallery Activity or even the Main Menu.

I've read that there are ways to perform this task under TouchUtils - using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, which a more of an automated testing tool.. 
I'm willing to go down this road as long that I can launch the OEM Activities that arrives with the device and send them the simulated touch events.

Is there a way to do so? Is there anything in MotionEvent that could help? (other then creating the actual touch event)

Thanks for helping,

Ita

Comment: Do you want to send touch events from the android device itself or
Do you want to send it events from PC connected to the device over adb?

Comment: Hi, I want to be able to simulate the touch events as if they were performed by a user touching the device.